# In Kusto how to get extra columns while using "reduce" operator

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

As per the documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/reduceoperator

"**reduce**" operator returns a table with three columns (**Pattern**, **Count**, and **Representative**).

For example, the result of reduce by city might include:

```
TABLE 1
Pattern Count   Representative
San *   5182    San Bernard
Saint * 2846    Saint Lucy
```

Now what if I want to get some extra column with this result? Is there any way to do so?
Basically I want to use that extra column as "foreignkey " for some other table.

Assuming that this is the limitation of "reduce" operator, so is there any way to get this result in a "TEMP Table", like in MSSQLServer we have a way to store an output of sql queriy into a #tempTable?

Answer (score 1):

At this moment 'reduce' operator does not allow carrying forward additional columns in its output. You may suggest and upvote such addition at https://aka.ms/adx.uservoice

If you have a sub-query that you would like to materialize for the query-lifetime: use materialize() function: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/materializefunction

For creating tables based on query results that can outlive specific query: you can use .set-or-append command: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-ingestion/ingest-from-query